# Calculate the output amount using MiniNero

Tags: ringct, mininero

Referring to the question [11272](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/11272/), I have an experiment with MiniNero:

```
tx_pub_key = "f6d51a0cabd6a68f2c4960bc06b4132d6b937622b8954ea95851aa5f3b32c1de"
pri_view_key = "89a705a1a6427e7a19fd17a78d4a5c35bcb9ce4af74d6c180d5e39909694ab0a"
aR = MiniNero.mul8(MiniNero.scalarmultKey(tx_pub_key, pri_view_key))
tmp = MiniNero.cn_fast_hash(aR+"00")
res = MiniNero.cn_fast_hash("616d6f756e74"+tmp) #616d6f756e74 is ASCII of "amount"
```

Then I get the result:

```
0e37ec1966076a6c5c6f15b1ad32f415b5f3e2426c1dc8c95c73b72cabe02168
```

The last step is to XOR each first 8-byte data:

```
amount = MiniNero.xor("54f95f7d7f4d1e2a", "0e37ec1966076a6c")
```

However, the result is not right. Am I doing something wrong? Please help to solve this, Thanks!

BTW, I get `54f95f7d7f4d1e2a` from `ecdhInfo` ([explorer](https://community.xmr.to/explorer/stagenet/tx/11a60ee431d2142fe95c7fd9469020794fcc6126f9429fa35ead03ca786d7d68/1))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't reduced `tmp`. I.e.

```
tmp = MiniNero.sc_reduce_key(MiniNero.cn_fast_hash(aR+"00"))
```

`Hs` in the referenced question's [answer](https://monero.stackexchange.com/a/11273/7493) refers to **H**ash to **s**calar, not simply hash. Otherwise `keccak` would have been written in place of `Hs`.

Thus, following your experiment through with the correction, I calculate 1 XMR:

```
tx_pub_key = "f6d51a0cabd6a68f2c4960bc06b4132d6b937622b8954ea95851aa5f3b32c1de"
pri_view_key = "89a705a1a6427e7a19fd17a78d4a5c35bcb9ce4af74d6c180d5e39909694ab0a"
aR = MiniNero.mul8(MiniNero.scalarmultKey(tx_pub_key, pri_view_key))
tmp = MiniNero.sc_reduce_key(MiniNero.cn_fast_hash(aR+"00"))
res = MiniNero.cn_fast_hash("616d6f756e74"+tmp) #616d6f756e74 is ASCII of "amount"
amount = MiniNero.xor("54f95f7d7f4d1e2a",res[:16])[:16]
print(MiniNero.hexToInt(amount)*1e-12)
```

Which yields:

```
1.0
```

Comment: Thanks you very much!!
BTW, does it indicate that it should multiple *1e-12 after the resource? Where can I find it?

Comment: https://web.getmonero.org/resources/moneropedia/atomic-units.html - 1 XMR is 1,000,000,000,000 atomic units. As amounts are stored in atomic units, to view in XMR one must multiply by 1e-12.

Comment: May I know why it needs to hexToInt() in the last step? Is there a monero-project version of hexToInt()? Thanks!

Comment: Because most of the *MiniNero* python methods return hex *strings*. The last step above needs it as an *integer* to multiply by 1e-12 to convert atomic units to XMR.