# Build RCT for new(?) format

Tags: ringct, mymonero

I'm trying to build a Monero transaction using the `mymonero-core` library. So far I've been following the code from the tests, however I'm not quite sure what to do with the "rct" part of the previous output. Here ([ref](https://github.com/mymonero/mymonero-core-js/blob/master/tests/sendingFunds.spec.js#L132))
the rct in constructed as the string concatenation of `outpk[i],mask[i],amount[i]`, which is possible because the used transaction `9d37c7fdeab91abfd1e7e120f5c49eac17b7ac04a97a0c93b51c172115df21ea` has all these fields:

```
""rct_signatures"": {
    ""type"": 3, 
    ""txnFee"": 327860000, 
    ""ecdhInfo"": [ {
        ""mask"": ""889e4a48335cbbf163ca9cd0299df86f28818ebb45960e0dd00e3f1a0549a704"", 
        ""amount"": ""9b07dcf00b7bf6cbdf269da3d9772af2ae377e1f58f13158359f6c96bfd2e50d""
      }, {
        ""mask"": ""b5b234ccdd70beca8b1fc8de4f2ceb1374e0f1fd8810849e7f11316c2cc06306"", 
        ""amount"": ""0008ffa5ac9827b776993468df21af8c963d12148622354f950cbe1369a92a0c""
      }], 
    ""outPk"": [ ""3ef9880e8fed3f5222096938a6bc773d2a12cbbc9caf30d12bc6a216b4fad70b"", ""86a2c9f1f8e66848cd99bfda7a14d4ac6c3525d06947e21e4e55fe42a368507e""]
  },
```

In my case however the transaction which I want to use UTXOs from has this structure

```
""rct_signatures"": {
    ""type"": 4, 
    ""txnFee"": 30790000, 
    ""ecdhInfo"": [ {
        ""amount"": ""54dd48f41f3670f3""
      }, {
        ""amount"": ""c0c11a7c62dc0f68""
      }], 
    ""outPk"": [ ""f4449d60fbc9087f9dcfa856537b4d2d02433454ba5245d4d46ea36ea5922c46"", ""29660983d695b61492d9a213c150da443997f8c9397e2910a07717fbda87f64d""]
  },
```

So the `mask` is missing and `amount` has a different format. How do I build RCT for those?

Comment: This should answer your question: https://monero.stackexchange.com/a/11273/7493

Comment: @jtgrassie Thanks for help, however it's still not quite clear if the RCT format stays the same? Do I still need to build it using a regular string concat once I got encrypted amount and mask in the "old"(?) format? Unfortunately this step is missing from the tests with only the resulting value being hard-coded

Comment: I've reopened (for now) but perhaps you should rewrite the question. The mask and amount are discussed in the other Q/A as the masks are now deterministically derived. Therefore they do not form part of the transaction any longer. And: "if the RCT format stays the same" is clearly no. type 3 is not the same as type 4.

Comment: @jtgrassie oh I see, do you by chance know if this implementation should be fine (for type`4`?)? https://github.com/monero-project/monero/blob/master/src/crypto/crypto.cpp#L515 it's really hard to find any docs or code samples for it

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to achieve. You link (in the question) to a mock test which gets the output of an RPC call, then in the comment above link to a function which generates a signature. What precisely are you trying to do? Build a tx? Sign?

Comment: @jtgrassie that test is using values from a real tx and passes the crypto checks. I'm trying to repeat it using my real tx but I get errors like `spendable_amount can't be 0` which I assume come from the fact that I don't build a proper rct (since other parts look good). My final goal is to build a valid tx string that I could later broadcast via the daemon given the valid UTXO (posted in the question) and the spend key for it